# Javascript replace & changing sting from a vriable

Tags: javascript

I have a URL `https://example.com/fullimg.php?eid=1&pgno=&pdate=2022-12-24`,

I want to create a next and previous button. If the user clicks on the next button he will redirect to `pgno=1` means the next page. If he clicks on the next button again he will be redirected to `pgno=2` and so on if he clicks next again he will be redirected to pgno=3 here the `pdate` is dynamic and changes every day.

I have tried this

```
      let url = window.location.href;
      if (url.includes("pgno=")) {
        url = url.replace("pgno=", "pgno=2");
      } else if (url.includes("pgno=2")) {
        url = url.replace("pgno=", "pgno=3");
      }
      console.log(url);
      window.location.replace(url);
```

Also I have tried this

```
      let url = window.location.href;
      if (url.includes("pgno=")) {
        url = url.replace("pgno=", "pgno=2");
      } 
      if (url.includes("pgno=2")) {
        url = url.replace("pgno=", "pgno=3");
      }
      console.log(url);
      window.location.replace(url);
```

For both it's only executing first condition not the 2nd one. After clicking on the next button it's going to `pgno=2` but after that when I am clicking next it's still reloading and redirecting to `pgno=2`

How can I solve it?

I have solved it, thanks to @Unmitigated

this is the function,

```
    function Next2() {
      let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
      // get the value of pgno
      let pgno = +params.get('pgno');
      // check if pgno is less than or equal to 12
      if (pgno <= 11) {
        // go to next page
        params.set('pgno', pgno + 1);
        location.search = params;
      }
    }
```

And here is the previous function

```
    function Prev1() {
      let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
      // get the value of pgno
      let pgno = +params.get('pgno');
      // check if pgno is greater than 1
      if (pgno > 1) {
        // go to previous page
        params.set('pgno', pgno - 1);
        location.search = params;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Nice reading [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to facilitate handling query strings.

```js
let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
// go to next page
params.set('pgno', +params.get('pgno') + 1);
location.search = params;
```

Comment: Thanks, working. But how can I stop it when it reaches 12? And will it work for previous button if I use `params.set('pgno', +params.get('pgno') -1);` and stop when pgno is 1?

Comment: @MohammadFathiRahman You would need to manually check for the page number being equal to 1 or 12.